# Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0) -Angular 15

Tags: angular, webpack, sass

I am pretty new to the webpack and I understand that there are multiple discussions available on this particular issue. But it looks like my issue is bit different as almost all of them are making use of custom webpack config, but I am not. I am migrating from Angular 14 to Angular 15 and uninstalled node-sass and installed sass.

This is how the options are configured under architect/build in angular.json

```
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
"options": {
    "outputPath": "dist",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
    "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
    "assets": ["src/assets"],
    "styles": [
        "src/styles/app/global.scss",
        "./node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "./node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/nova-alt/theme.css",
        "./node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
        "src/styles/vendors/font-awesome.css",
        "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
        "./node_modules//quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
        "./node_modules/quill-mention/dist/quill.mention.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
        "./node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
        "node_modules/quill-mention/dist/quill.mention.min.js"
    ]
}
```

When I issue ng serve, I get the below error:

```
./src/styles/app/global.scss?ngGlobalStyle:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0) 
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> @charset "UTF-8";
| @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;700&display=swap"); /*!
|  * Bootstrap v3.4.0 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
```

my global.sccss uses:

```
@use '../vendors/bootstrap';
@use 'custom-primeng-style';
@use 'custom-quill-style';
@use 'colors';
@use 'fonts';
```